# 'docker run ...' hangs at execuring sh script

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, dockerfile

So I have this Dockerfile, which builds a React app, and then serves it. It is working just fine. However, as soon as I add a shell script to be executed within CMD, the image builds, but hangs indefinetely when run.

I followed this tutorial: [adding env variables to nginx docker](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/)

```sh
# Stage 0, build-stage, based on Node.js to build the frontend
FROM node:alpine as build
MAINTAINER Kuba Wasilewski <jakub.wasilewski@sprint.pl>
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN apk add --update python make g++\
   && rm -rf "/var/cache/apk/*"
RUN npm install
COPY . /app/
RUN npm run build

# Stage 1, run-phase, based on NGINX to provide SSL configuration and serve static files
FROM nginx:alpine
MAINTAINER Kuba Wasilewski <jakub.wasilewski@sprint.pl>
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY nginx/server.cert /etc/nginx
COPY nginx/server.key /etc/nginx
EXPOSE 443

# working CMD
# CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

# changes Ive applied
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/env.sh .
COPY nginx/.env .
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN chmod +x env.sh
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

Comment: Only thing that looks a bit off is the RUN in your first image. Why do you install python and  make and stuff? In the next image this won't be available anymore, and you are not using it, and you don't need it.

Comment: Without Python I can't run npm install for some reason.. Also, I know it's not the script itself, as I tried to use a 'echo "hello"' script, with the same result...

Comment: you are also installing bash first. Can you run the container in interactive mode and confirm you can run bash commands without issue?

Comment: I think you can get away with doing apk update. This should allow you to install node. It just happens to be that you run this along you python and make install. But this is not your issue. Its something else that's slightly off but should still work. Usually you have to run a apt update or apk or whatever, on new server and docker images to get available package list.

Comment: @TheFool I mean the test 'hello' script runs just fine, but still hangs...

Comment: You don't copy the script to the location you run it from though. How is this possible? You copy it to `/env.sh` but run it from `/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh`.  

This would also be a bad place for this script. HTML folder is supposed to contain content that nginx will server over http. I dont think your script with env vars should be part of that.

Comment: @TheFool ...I forgot about my WORKDIR, edited my question. Also, it's useful for me to place the script there, as it creates an additional js file right there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228689/discussion-between-the-fool-and-k-wasilewski).

Comment: What's actually in the `env.sh` script?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else encounters this issue, the actual solution is `COPY build/myscript.sh /docker-entrypoint.d/myscript.sh` and add `RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.d/myscript.sh` in the Dockerfile.

You can leave `CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` at the end.

This will work because nginx:alpine will run the scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/ before starting nginx. If you try using sh or bash with nginx inside then it will hang.